# Fine-grained Access for DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I am trying to have a fine grained access policy setup for my DynamoDB Rows.

Scenario: I have an IAM user in multiple workspaces. So we have established a Custom Attribute named “workspace” and to this we are having a comma delimited values (i.e. workspace ID’s)

Now we want to establish a policy to filter access only to Rows where the WSID is in the IAM workspace attribute.

Can someone help me on this; or is there are better way to implement this.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am trying to implement it using google login. And I have done all the setup. But when I try to query dynamodb using a specific user I get Access Denied. I have already created a row with that user's sub value. So I am not sure if I am missing something.